# jQuery exception with runat="server" in script declaration

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have an issue with declaring the jQuery 3.3.1 script in the head element throwing an exception inside of the jQuery source. I'm using runat="server" in order to have the path resolve properly when run while still preserving the intellisense while I'm coding. It throws an exception with the following error:

> CS1519: Invalid token '!' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

I'm assuming the issue is that Visual Studio is trying to debug jQuery and finding what it considers errors.

What I'm wondering is if there's either a way to use runat="server" and ignore exceptions in jQuery, or if there's a different way to include jQuery using a path with ~/ in it. I've used ResolveUrl() to include jQuery, which works, but intellisense breaks for me when I do that.

The current code I'm using is:

```
<head runat="server">
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.min.js" runat="server" />
</head>
```

As a side note, the reason I'm attempting to use ~/ is that I'm linking to the script in a master page, so the relative path may change depending on the folder that the aspx path is in. If there's another way to accomplish this, I'd accept that as well.

Comment: Why not simply use `<script src="/Scripts/jquery.min.js" />`

Comment: Because my website isn't always going to be deployed to the root of the server